# Create script/shortcut to login via ssh

Tags: ssh, login-script

My issue is that everytime I have to login to a given account on a linux server (there are many) I have to go pull a text file not I have to look at the username and ip.

Example: "ssh some_user@xxx.xxx.xxx.x -pxxxxx"

I want to make my life a little easier by creating a shortcut, e.g. "ssh some_user"...

I searched and could not find an answer, likely not using the right terminology.

Thanks!

Comment: Really? I just want to tell you that this is NOT the way to do it. But ist up to you. All other readers, please use `man ssh-keygen`, `man ssh-copy-id` and `man ssh_config`. How do you want to script this? ssh without config is interactive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ssh client configuration file](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) (`.ssh/config`). If you have to type `ssh -p 1234 mylogin@my.server.with.a.long.name.com`, you can populate your config file with

```
host server
    hostname my.server.with.a.long.name.com
    user mylogin
    port 1234
```

Then you can simply type `ssh server` and it will have the same effect. You can have as many entries in your `.ssh/config` file as you want and even use wildcards (`*`)

If you are using a recent version of bash, you can furthermore make use of the `command_not_found_handle` function:

```
command_not_found_handle () {
    if grep "host $1" ~/.ssh/config &>/dev/null; then
        ssh $@
    else
       printf "Sorry: Command not found: $1\n"
       return 127
    fi
}
```

Then you can connect simply with

```
server
```

Comment: is there any difference in suing a config file vs. alias?

Comment: First, using a configuration file will allow you to use wildcards (for instance if you want to use the same port on all hosts) but most importantly, it will also work for other SSH-based tools: scp, rsync, etc. And it is much cleaner to organize and copy around than a set of aliases

Comment: And the article you reference in your comment reads, at some point, 'However, there’s a much more elegant and flexible solution to this problem. Enter the SSH config file'

Comment: Yes, I changed to the ssh config as this is a better way to do this. Still learning. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I understood your problem correct, but a proper ssh config file make life muuuch easier. No IP, no domain, no password, not even a username.

See the man page: http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config

I like things like `ssh vm`, or `scp vm:...` no more `scp blablubb@192.168.226.xy:...`+ passphrase.

Also see `ssh-keygen` and `ssh-copy-id` for asymmetric key exchange. Will get you rid of typing passwords.

Generally I recommend to read a ssh tutorial.